# SMTP Authentication without using IP

Tags: windows-server-2008, smtp, windows-authentication

On my local machine, I wish to send mail through SMTP on my Windows Server.

I understand that I need to authorise my machine's local IP in relay restrictions. However, this is not ideal as I'll need to modify this everytime my IP changes.

Is there any more flexible way in which I can authorise this connection? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would your (internal) ip address change?

Comment: @joeqwerty I use my development machine in multiple locations. Apologies if I didn't make myself clear.

Comment: Setup a VPN to your network or the server, assign yourself a static IP in the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

The IPs of `localhost`, i. e. `127.0.0.1` and `::1`, don't change very frequently.